# How should I draw this in a game?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, opengl-es, libgdx

I'm beginning to develop games for android and I have what I believe a pretty simple question. I'm trying to replicate the game 'The Impossible Game' which is shown below for some practice. I'm having trouble with the white line the player uses as the "ground". When I want to create it, should I create is as its own texture and draw it like that on a texture atlas map and then put it into my game level picture and use collision detection, or should I just create that line in the background image and say if players position y = number, then stop falling? And then scroll the camera upwards when the player goes higher so the line doesn't always stay at that part of the screen. Which is an easier approach? hanks guys. I'm just not sure what's easier.

[image: Impossible Game]

Comment: What's keeping you from just drawing a line?

Comment: If there is more than one entity moving besides the player (absolute position) I would recommend using collision rather than relying on coordinates.

Comment: Alright so I'll just create a line texture and render that like I did for the squares and use the collision detection. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ShapeRenderer](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html) to draw a line like this:

```
//x,y your first point, x2,y2 your second point
shapeRenderer.line(x, y, x2, y2);
```

If you want to have the same effect like in the image you posted (with the limits of the line fading), you can divide it in 3 lines, one small going from full transparency color to white, one all white being the longest of them, and one going from full white to full transparency in the other end.

Something like this:

```
white = new Color(1,1,1,1);
transp = new Color(1,1,1,0);

shapeRenderer.line(x, y, x2, y2, transp, white); //Transp. to white
shapeRenderer.line(x2, y2, x3, y3, white, white); //all White
shapeRenderer.line(x3, y3, x4, y4, white, transp); //White to transp
```

Just set the correct points. (And do not create new [Color](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Color.html)s every frame!)

Of course you can also make a [TextureRegion](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureRegion.html) inside your atlas all white (even a 1x1 will do the trick). And just render that at the size and position you want.

```
batch.draw(whiteregion, x, y, width, height);
```